# jQuery: Event binding

Tags: jquery, html, bind

I have a select with size 4, problem is that I can click on any option, and without releasing the mouse button, just moving the cursor up or bottom, I can select other options. How to bind this event with jQuery? `.change()` event works exactly.

**Html code**

```
<select name="test" size="4">
<option value="1">value 1</option>
<option value="2">value 2</option>
<option value="3">value 3</option>
<option value="4">value 4</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$('select[name="test"] option').each(function(){
     $(this).on("click",
       function() {
          //do
       });
});
```

Comment: MouseHold event plugin perhaps?

Comment: Can't you just use `.change()` (on the `select` element) instead? On a side note you don't need to iterate through the options (-> `.each()`) - `.on()` will do this automatically when applied to a collection.

Comment: thanks for Your reply, but with .change() event works exactly like code above with .on().

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't handle event on `<option>` tag. If you handle `change` event on `<select>` tag the jquery event handler works correctly.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/avall/YyHAD/4/

Answer (score 0):

Check the mousedown event in Jquery. This [link](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use change() on the select:

```
$('select[name="test"]').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xKDM6/